# Configure Doxygen to hide certain names or keywords

Tags: c, doxygen

I'm just getting started with Doxygen, and have done considerable searching on this, so forgive me if there's an obvious answer.

I'm working on an embedded project where functions can be tagged as `debug` or `nodebug` before the return type.  In most of our libraries, we use a conditional macro to set `libname_debug` to either `debug` or `nodebug` at the top of the file, and then each function is prefaced with `libname_debug`.

For documentation purposes, I'd like to have Doxygen leave `libname_debug` out of the function documentation.  It clutters up the function list and makes it harder to see the return types of each function.

Is it possible to tag the file in some way so Doxygen will leave that symbol out?  At the moment, I'm wrapping each instance in @cond/@endcond:

```
/** @cond */ libname_debug /** @endcond */
```

But that's a pain and adds extra markup to the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define macros in the doxygen configuration file. Something like this

```
PREDEFINED += libname_debug
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the starting point I needed.  I had to update the source to not define libname_debug if it was already defined, add it to the PREDEFINED list, and then turn on MACRO_EXPANSION and EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF.  I was hopeful that the pattern `*_debug` in EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS would work, but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 6):

There is also a [doxygen page](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html) explaining how to handle such situations. You would enable `MACRO_EXPANSION` (which defaults to `NO`), tell doxygen to only expand some macros (`EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF`) and add your symbol as macro with an empty expansion:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = libname_debug=
```

Comment: +1 for being clear. But what with this last "equal" at `libname_debug=` ? Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: `libname_debug=` is correct it means that the macro `libname_debug` is expanded with "an empty expansion". Please have a look at the linked doxgen page.